# Server 2012 R2 backup and restore

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2, backup-restoration, windows-server-backup

I do not have much experience with backup/restore to windows server images.  I have a Windows server 2012r2 with sql and an accounting program.  It is/was joined to a domain.   I had to do a restore from backup image (I use Novastor backup server).  The server had spinning disks and I replaced them with solid state discs, then did the restore on them.  The server now does not allow me to login with my active directory credentials, just the local Admin.  I don’t think it is linked to the domain properly anymore.  Any advice on what I need to do to get this back to normal?
I really was hoping the restore from Image backup would work without issue, but maybe it did not because of the new hardware installed?  I do not want to do a fresh install and have to reinstall & reconfigure everything.
Thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: why cant you use the local credentials? at least that would get you back into the box for further troubleshooting. This must not be a DC, right?  Login locally, then rejoin the domain.

Comment: Did you try to restore to the same server? Maybe it is a driver issue and your server could not connect to your AD?

Comment: This is not really superuser.com - this is a place from the site rules for professionals following proper business practices. Starting with "I do not really know what I am doing" sort of makes me vote to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume, it happens bacause of "computer credentials" change. Computer account password refresh is automatic process that happens between computer and domain controller without notification to or interaction with the user.
Check 2-nd reason [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/9157.troubleshooting-ad-trust-relationship-between-workstation-and-primary-domain-failed.aspx)

Just login with local Admin and rejoin domain.

Comment: Thanks batistuta09.  I will look at just rejoining the domain as you have pointed out.

Comment: I was thinking that I could also do a P2V on this to make life much easier as well.

Comment: For P2V, I'd advise to check this article regarding convertors - https://www.hyper-v.io/migrating-cloud-easy-experience-choosing-p2v-converters/